# Hide pop-up menu item in eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a plug-in for eclipse.
I am trying to hide one menu item from a pop-up menu.
The pop up menu shows up when right clicking in one of my views.

I have found a couple of online tutorials but I don't get the expected result.
It seems I don't get anctivity & activityPatternBinding to work. Not even when I try to hide all elements (pattern=".*").

Here it is an snippet of my code:

```xml
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">  
    <activity id="myActivity" name="MenuHidingActivity">  
    </activity>
    <activityPatternBinding 
        activityId="myActivity"
        pattern="IdOfTheMenuItemToBeRemoved">  
    </activityPatternBinding>
</extension>
```

I'm using Eclipse version 3.6.2.
Any guideline would be much appreciated :)

Comment: you are right, it may be solved by using the other post. thanks a lot greg-449!